# Eloquent relationship Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, git-bash

I have two models. Article and User. In Article I have this function

```
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

in user have this function

```
 public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
    }
```

in the git bash after giving php artisan tinker command, when I gave `App\Article::first();`

it shows the first article of the database.

```
$user=App\User::first();
```

this command can show the 1st user.

but when I gave

```
 $user->articles->toArray();
```

this command it shows that

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Call to a member function toArray() on null
```

but as per shown in tutorial, it should show the articles of user 1.

Comment: `$user=App\User::with('articles')->first();`

Comment: It does not work either

Comment: Check your article table on phpMyAdmin or Mysql Workbench and see if the foreign key exists

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eloquent: Relationships of laravel

**1. One To Many**

Assume 1 User have many Article

in model of user:

```
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Article','user_id');
    }
```

in model of articles

```
public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
```

Get all articles belong to User

```
$user = App\User::with('articles')->get();
$articles = $user->articles;
```

**I hope help you!**

Comment: Edited code like you said. but 

BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::articles()'

Comment: Oh sorry i edited:  $user = App\User::with('articles')->get();
$articles = $user->articles;

Comment: somehow my articles() method is detected as undefined. :\

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons:

1 `aritcles` does not have foreign key name `user_id` referencing `user` model

2 Since the foreign key is not named as `user_id` you must explicitly define the foreign key name while defining relationship.

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','foreign_key');
}    
public function articles(){    
 return $this->hasMany('App\Article','foreign_key');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to fetch the article, the `users` table should have a `article_id` field or the `articles` table should have a `user_id` field. Furthermore, the first article you return, try `$article->user` and check which `user` is being returned.

The error, you reported is because NO ARTICLE is associated with the given user. In other words, the article doesn't have a `user_id` set to current user's id.

Comment: My article table has user_id.
 Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
          //  $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->timestamp('published_at');

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });

Comment: $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

Comment: // $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned(); .. remove //.. then execute `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Comment: see the database table `articles`